# Security Model for multiple LOB's

Tags: apex, visualforce, profile, security, owd

We have 3 Line Of businesses(A, B & c) in one org, sharing the account and contact standard object. I would like to know you thoughts and best approach to maintain good data/security model.

1) how can i avoid duplicate accounts(Say A creates an account - Nike Inc, then B or C may also work with Nike Inc.) How to handle this kind of situation?

2) Security of Account or Contacts? Best approach to handle this by setting OWD to private and increase access with sharing rules?
or 
Set OWD to read only and control access using profiles(if profiles have Modify all/view all overrides OWD - is private)/permission sets etc.,

Or any other thoughts?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to avoid duplicate creation of Accounts, user should have visibility of all three LOB.

Either you can give OWD as private and open up access with sharing rule or other means.

or, you can define OWD as Public Read Only if all the users in the organization will see all the accounts.

Also, to avoid creating duplicate records you can leverage [Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&type=0)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sometimes they will be sharing the accounts among the LOB's. so what should be the OWD set too?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to have "duplicate" accounts, because each account represents a different line of business, and so they're not really duplicates. This is especially true for reporting, forecasting, etc.

However, if you want to avoid duplicate accounts while still reasonably restricting view access, consider Territory Management instead. You'll want to test this out in a Sandbox before you commit to it, but you can assign accounts and opportunities to various territories for sharing and reporting purposes.

Contacts are generally always available to whomever can view the account, but you will be able to hide opportunities based on the line of business, which should be sufficient in most cases.

Finally, if you decouple the contacts from the accounts (set contact OWD to private), you can set up criteria-based sharing rules so that each LOB can see their own accounts, contacts, and opportunities based on some criteria, such as a custom field that you could set.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sometimes they will be sharing the accounts among the LOB's. so what should be the OWD set to?

Comment: @mvr It would still be Private, but you'll need to set up Sharing Rules, Account Teams, or Territory Management. Territory Management would probably be the easiest, though it requires a little more setup.